# Input 0 of layer "conv2d_transpose_4" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 100)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to develop a GAN, I have created the generator and the discriminator and now I am trying to train it. I am using the Mnist dataset but I plan to use some more. The problem is that when I train it I get this error: `Input 0 of layer "conv2d_transpose_4" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 100)`

I don't really know if the problem is in the networks or in the data used to train the GAN, can someone tell me how should I train it or where the problem is?

imports:

```
import tensorflow
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Input, BatchNormalization, 
LeakyReLU, Reshape
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras import backend as K
from keras.utils import np_utils

from keras.datasets import mnist

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2
```

generator:

```
def generator():
   model = Sequential()
   model.add(Conv2DTranspose(32, (3,3), strides=(2, 
   2), activation='relu', use_bias=False, 
   input_shape=img_shape))
   model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.3))
   model.add(Conv2DTranspose(128,(3,3),strides= 
   (2,2), activation='relu', padding='same', 
   use_bias=False)) 
   model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
   model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))

   model.add(Conv2DTranspose(128,(3,3),strides= 
   (2,2), activation='relu', padding='same', 
   use_bias=False))
   model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
   model.add(Dropout(0.5))
   model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.3))
   model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))

   model.add(Conv2DTranspose(128,(3,3),strides= 
   (2,2), activation='relu', padding='same', 
   use_bias=False))
   model.add(BatchNormalization())
   model.add(Dense(512, 
   activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)))
   model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.7))

   model.build()
   model.summary()
   return model
```

discriminator:

```
def discriminator():
   model = Sequential()
   model.add(Conv2D(32, (5,5), strides=(2, 2), 
   activation='relu', use_bias=False, 
   input_shape=img_shape))
   model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.3))
   model.add(Conv2D(64,(5,5),strides=(2,2), 
   activation='relu', padding='same', 
   use_bias=False))
   model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
   model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))

   model.add(Conv2D(64,(5,5),strides=(2,2), 
   activation='relu', padding='same', 
   use_bias=False))
   model.add(Dropout(0.5))
   model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.3))
   model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))

   model.add(Dense(512, 
   activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)))
   model.add(Flatten())
   model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.7))
   model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

   model.build()
   model.summary()

   return model
```

train function:

```
def train(epochs, batch_size, save_interval):

(x_train, _), (_, _) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = (x_train.astype(np.float32) - 127.5) / 127.5
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=3) 
half_batch = int(batch_size / 2)

for epoch in range(epochs):
    idx = np.random.randint(0, x_train.shape[0], half_batch)
    imgs = x_train[idx]

    noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (half_batch, 100))

    gen_imgs = generator.predict(noise)

    d_loss_real = discriminator.train_on_batch(imgs, np.ones((half_batch, 1)))
    d_loss_fake = discriminator.train_on_batch(gen_imgs, np.zeros((half_batch, 1)))

    d_loss = 0.5 * np.add(d_loss_real, d_loss_fake) 
    noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (batch_size, 100)) 
    valid_y = np.array([1] * batch_size)
    g_loss = combined.train_on_batch(noise, valid_y)

    print ("%d [D loss: %f, acc.: %.2f%%] [G loss: %f]" % (epoch, d_loss[0], 100*d_loss[1], g_loss))
    if epoch % save_interval == 0:
        save_imgs(epoch)
```

Data used:

```
img_rows = 28
img_cols = 28
channels = 1
img_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, channels)

optimizer = Adam(0.0002, 0.5)
discriminator = discriminator()
discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
optimizer=optimizer,
metrics=['accuracy'])

generator = generator()
generator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', 
optimizer=optimizer)

z = Input(shape=(100,))
img = generator(z) #error

discriminator.trainable = False  

valid = discriminator(img)

combined = Model(z, valid)
combined.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', 
optimizer=optimizer)


train(epochs=100000, batch_size=32, 
save_interval=10)

generator.save('generator_model.h5')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is coming from the first `Flatten` layer in the `Discriminator` model, which is converting your n-dimensional tensor to a 1D tensor. Since a `MaxPooling2D` layer cannot work with a 1D tensor, you are seeing that error. If you remove it, it should work:

```
def discriminator():
   model = Sequential()
   model.add(Conv2D(32, (5,5), strides=(2, 2), 
   activation='relu', use_bias=False, 
   input_shape=img_shape))
   model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.3))
   model.add(Conv2D(64,(5,5),strides=(2,2), 
   activation='relu', padding='same', 
   use_bias=False))
   model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
   model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))

   model.add(Conv2D(64,(5,5),strides=(2,2), 
   activation='relu', padding='same', 
   use_bias=False))
   model.add(Dropout(0.5))
   model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.3))
   model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))

   model.add(Flatten())
   model.add(Dense(512, 
   activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)))
   model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.7))
   model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

   model.build()
   model.summary()

   return model
```

**Update 1**:
Try rewriting your `Generator` model like this:

```
def generator():
  model = Sequential()

  model = tf.keras.Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(7*7*256, use_bias=False, input_shape=(100,)))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(LeakyReLU())

  model.add(Reshape((7, 7, 256)))
  assert model.output_shape == (None, 7, 7, 256)  # Note: None is the batch size

  model.add(Conv2DTranspose(128, (5, 5), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', use_bias=False))
  assert model.output_shape == (None, 7, 7, 128)
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(LeakyReLU())

  model.add(Conv2DTranspose(64, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False))
  assert model.output_shape == (None, 14, 14, 64)
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(LeakyReLU())

  model.add(Conv2DTranspose(1, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False, activation='tanh'))
  assert model.output_shape == (None, 28, 28, 1)

  model.summary()
  return model
```

It should then work, but you should definitely go through this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan) to understand everything.

Comment: I removed it and the error changed: 'Input 0 of layer "conv2d_transpose" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 100)'  The error now is in the: img = generator(z) line. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: Your code seems to have multiple errors..Can you add all your imports to your question

Comment: I added the imports, for sure I am missing some concepts, I'm new with keras

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, It worked, I will follow the tutorial to get the knowledge

Answer (score 1):

**First the discriminator is wrong you expecting the input noise to generator with same diemnsions where it is similaities for crossentrory**, noises can generate into multiple levels where the batch is create !

WHen you looking at each layer you will see how much the layer identification need !

Simply doing by measure the input / output you don't need to removed or edit meaning of the model.

**It is not the generator flase** when you input is wrong try see the discriminator layers where they are training on the batch sizes and the genrated input image.
( It is noises similarlities cross-entrophy )

**Model layers and shapes is not chagne when you use the input correct way**

```
### name='conv2d_transpose_input'), name='conv2d_transpose_input', description="created by layer 'conv2d_transpose_input'"), 
### but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 100).
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2DTranspose(32, (3,3), strides=(2, 
2), activation='relu', use_bias=False, 
input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.3))
model.add(Conv2DTranspose(128,(3,3),strides= 
(2,2), activation='relu', padding='same', 
use_bias=False)) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))

########################
def discriminator():
model = Sequential()

### Input 0 of layer "conv2d" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1, but received input with shape (None, 114, 114, 512)
### model.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1, 100), input_shape=img_shape))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (5,5), strides=(2, 2), 
activation='relu', use_bias=False, 
input_shape=( 28, 28, 1)))  ### img_shape
model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.3))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(5,5),strides=(2,2), 
activation='relu', padding='same', 
use_bias=False))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
```

[My sample is gradients values from motions of the Heriken kicks !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kamtp.png)